# checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after event issue

Tags: event-observer, magento-1.6, payment-methods, paypal-express

I have used `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after`. Means every time someone purchases some product, I want Magento to perform some action.

I have Paypal's "Website Payments Pro" and "Express Checkout" enabled. The above event seems to be working fine with "Website Payments Pro" but doesn't  seem to be working for "Express Checkout". My `Config.xml` is as follows.

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
                <observers>
                    <checkout_order>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>classgroupName/observer</class>
                        <method>someMethod</method>
                    </checkout_order>
                </observers>
            </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Which method should I use? Is there any common Event for both payment methods?

Answer (score 4):

Transaction Flow is bit different in case of "Express Checkout".

I suggest you to use `sales_order_place_after` event and use payment method code to check for suitable payment method:

```
$orderObject = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$paymentMethodCode = $orderObject->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
```

Comment: Thanks. should I use this "sales_order_place_after" event regardless of any Payment Option? Means will this event work of any given Payment type?